# Tomcat to Tomee

Tags: java

I have a jsf application using cdi implemented with weld. I have been running it successfully on tomcat 8 and I thought using the same app on tomee was just a matter of dropping it into tomee webapp directory without any modification but unfortunately when I do that I get a 404 not found error. Please is there anything I am expected to do extra to get tomee working?

Answer (score 0):

In logs you should see myfaces starting and the used binding

Also ensure to remove weld from the application as well as EE api jars (CDI, annotations,...)